# Retry request ends with "Content length mismatch"

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, retrypolicy

My problem goes this way:

I have an Azure APIM, I have created an API and addeded the backend retry policy as below.

```
<backend>
    <retry condition="@("{{Transient-ErrorCode}}".Contains(Convert.ToString(context.Response.StatusCode)))" count="3" interval="5" first-fast-retry="false">
        <forward-request />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

The server return success(statuscode: 200) for the first time, When it initiate the retry it encountered the following(***I am retrying at its success also, for testing the retry is working fine.***).

```
forward-request (1.326 ms)
{
"messages": [
    "Content length mismatch",
    "Content length mismatch"
    ]
}
```

Please help with your thoughts/experience on the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because request sent by client is not cached in memory by default in APIM, instead it's streamed right from client to backend. So when needs come to retry the request request payload is not there. I assume that you have problems only with requests that have body.

To resolve the issue you first need to cache request body:

```
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="body" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <retry condition="@("{{Transient-ErrorCode}}".Contains(Convert.ToString(context.Response.StatusCode)))" count="3" interval="5" first-fast-retry="false">
        <set-body>@((string)context.Variables["body"])</set-body>
        <forward-request />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

Comment: What would be the best way to check that the request has a body? The use case would be for a global policy.

Comment: I have put in a check to see if the body is null, then set the variable to an empty string...but i am uncertain of side effects.

Comment: context.Request.HasBody

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an alternative simplification for including the body by using the attribute `buffer-request-body` on the `forward-request` policy:

```
<!-- no need to put body into variable in the inbound policy -->
<backend>
    <retry condition="@("{{Transient-ErrorCode}}".Contains(Convert.ToString(context.Response.StatusCode)))" count="3" interval="5" first-fast-retry="false">
        <!-- no need for the set-body policy -->
        <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

See [doco for forward-request's attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#attributes-1)

Comment: This is the way